# Date without time in long format

Tags: javascript

I'm able to get date in long format with time

```
new Date().getTime()
```

which return long with time

```
1626429691945
```

is it possible to return date in long without hour , minute ,seconds

Comment: you mean get the long date of the given day as it would be at midnight?

Comment: What do you mean "without hour minute seconds"? `getTime()` returns an epoch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log(new Date(new Date().toDateString()).getTime())
```

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not possible.

Because [Date.prototype.getTime()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) returns a `long` representing the number of milliseconds since the Epoch it ***necessarily*** represents a specific time.

If you want that `long` value the closest approximation to what you want would be to get the millisecond time of midnight of the date you want.

---

Nodar Sanaia's answer is a great way to *get* that midnight time.